# Why There is A White space on right side of website in Mobile devices

Tags: html, css, web, mobile

Why is there an empty white space on the right side of my mobile website display? like this [my error screeenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNaDx.png) and this is my [live link](https://raw.githack.com/hahamen-ihs/blue-cv/master/index.html)

I beg for your help and thank you :)

Comment: You have one too many closing `div` tags which may be causing the issue.

Comment: What happens in landscape mode? Try commenting out .topcloud, .bottomcloud in you css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in `awan.png` image. This image is `absolute` position for Mobile and Desktop. In smaller screen this image showing in outside of `.top-container`. You have two option to fix this issue.

**Option 1**

Using `@media` for mobile devices. You no need to use this cloud image for mobile devices.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .bottom-cloud{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Make `top-container` class overflow hidden.

```
.top-container{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-color: var(--biru-muda);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope this help!.

Comment: thanks :) i will try your suggestion, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

its your .bottom-cloud in the top-container what causes the issue.

```
<img class="bottom-cloud" src="img/awan.png" alt="">
```

it has a position:absolute with position out of the viewport which causes the viewport expanding.

Add an overflow:hidden to the top-container and it wont expand it.

Comment: thanks :) i will try your suggestion, thank you very much :)